# How to pass object to components in marko?

Tags: node.js, marko

Hello I am trying to call a component with an object as parameter but the component prints the object as string "[object Object]".
In the docs it specify object as an attribute type: https://marko-v4.github.io/docs/marko-json/

```
<vid-meta title=`${someObj}`/>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

solved rather writing `<vid-meta title="${someObj}"/>` i wrote `<vid-meta title=someObj />`

Comment: Just be careful with relying on `input.title` as you won't be notified on changes using an object.